Single pole switch to turn on/off 3 lights?
Can I use a single pole switch to turn on/off 3 single bulb lights in my shed?

Sure, if the lights are wired in parallel and the switch is in series with the hot. I would remind you that the load cannot exceed the rating of the switch, but you are highly unlikely to run into that limitation unless the bulbs are huge.

With respect, this is a pretty fundamental setup in residential wiring. If you have to ask, are you sure you can do this work safely? You can get killed by not doing it right.

Yes if you want all three to come on/off together.
You just connect the hot/live wire and the neutral wire to each light.
Light one to light two to light three.
Some light fixtures even have two sets(brass and silver) of screws for this connection.
